# How do I retrieve and display user details from mysql database in android studio?

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-studio, android-volley

So I have a database with a 'user' table that holds user details such as their username, password, age and full name (as well as a userID that auto increments). I was able to get my application to allow for a user registration, sending inputted details into the aforementioned table in my database and have been able to login to the app using those credentials. However I want to be able to show such details on a user page in my app. How would I do this? I am using volley library and json to interact with my php file.

Answer (score 0):

If you program is capable of making a call to the server and reading json data, printing the json in plain text should work.

`echo json_encode($data)`